# extract a text string after spaces and a symbol with gsub R

Tags: r, extract, gsub

I need to extract the first word (German) from the following text string

```
substr(details[1],0,50)%>%
+     gsub("[^a-z/A-Z/,/ ]","" ,.)%>%  
+     gsub("A-Z.*" , "", .)
[1] "  , German, European, Central European"
```

For many combinations I try with gsub I can't extract it

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share what is `substr(details[1],0,50)`  Or `details[1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string is `s <- "  , German, European, Central European"`, maybe you can use the following code to get the word `German`:

```
w <- gsub("\\s+,\\s+([[:alpha:]]+),.*","\\1",s)
```

or

```
w <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(s,split = ","))[2])
```